# How to install .tar.bz2 packages on Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, software-installation, package-management

I'm looking for ways to install, `firefox-89.0.tar.bz2` for example, on Fedora 34, and I can't figure out a way to do it.. So how would I install a `.tar.bz2` archive in Fedora, or RHEL based distros?

Comment: Why not use Firefox from the Fedora distro?

Comment: I just wanted to tryout the new release.. and found out that the latest it's not running yet as good as the the current `88.0.1`. Compared to Arch, where the `89.0` just rips.. So I guess, I just wanted to experiment.

Comment: `firefox-89.0-1.fc34` [has been built](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1757216) so I expect it should appear in the repos soon.  If the performance isn't good, perhaps you could file a [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/) report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Close firefox.
2. Navigate to the directory that contains the file.
3. Open a terminal in the directory (depending on your DE, you can right-click and select 'Open terminal').
4. Type `tar xjf firefox-*.tar.bz2` (note that you need to substitute the `*` with the version of firefox you have downloaded; i.e. the filename).
5. Run the `firefox` script which is inside the folder that was created during extraction.

EDIT: please try the steps under. **Be warned: this might mean that you will have to manually update `firefox` for every new version.**

1. Open up a terminal and write `sudo dnf remove -y firefox`.
2. Type `unlink /usr/bin/firefox` to unlink the symlink (if there is one).
3. Type `cd /usr/local`.
4. Download `firefox` to the current folder using `wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/89.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-89.0.tar.bz2`.
5. Extract the tarball using `tar xvjf firefox-89.0.tar.bz2`.
6. Source `firefox` to make it accessible from anywhere using `sudo ln -s /usr/local/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox`.
7. Reboot.

Comment: I've done this, before posting this question, I've seen it on youtube, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. You are basically saying that after extracting the tar archive and running the `firefox` script from that directory, that should somehow integrate it on the system, and update my actual version of `firefox`? I'm asking because I wanna understand how this works.

Comment: The procedure to extracting is always the same. Sometimes you need to `chmod` the content of the tarball in order to be able to run it. The script is just something that executes a piece of code that is meant to do something on the system it is being executed on. What error do you get when trying to run the firefox script?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but my `firefox_88` doesn't upgrade to version 89 -  which I'm trying to get for Fedora.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check the edit.

Comment: I have found this set of instructions yesterday on a website while searching for this, before seeing your answer. It works perfectly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think this exact process would work with any archive like `firefox's`, right?

Comment: It depends. The thing with `firefox` is that it's already pre-compiled; that's why it is possible to just create a symlink and access it from anywhere. If it weren't pre-compiled, you would have had to compile it yourself and then create the symlink. They're just a few extra steps, but that's mainly the reason why it is so hassle-free to install `firefox`. Anyway, sorry it took some time - I thought you were getting some error.